# Is there a way to export labels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, export

I've used the v2 labeling engine to place some nice looking road labels. Now I'd like to export those labels as a point shapefile for use in another program. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: what is the other program

Comment: The other program is OCAD.

Comment: I ask because QGIS doesn't seem to treat the labels as any kind of selectable objects. Or at least I don't know how to select them. OCAD doesn't have the ability to smart-label objects the way that QGIS does & if this can be done, it would save a lot of time.

Comment: Last month (Dec. 2013), Dr. Marco Hugentobler added _direct_ DXF export to the current development version of QGIS, i.e. the [master branch](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS). However, labels are not included in the new feature (yet?). You may wish to contact Marco via the [QGIS Dev mailing list](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/mailinglists.html) to see if he is planning on it, or if you are interested in funding its development.

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
fullext = canvas.mapRenderer().fullExtent()
f = 64
sx = fullext.xMinimum()
sy = fullext.yMinimum()
w = fullext.width()/f
h = fullext.height()/f
fileGrid = open("grid.txt","w")
for i in xrange(f): 
    for j in xrange(f): 
        rec = QgsRectangle(sx+i*w,sy+j*h,sx+(i+1)*w,sy+(j+1)*h)
        s = "%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f\n" % (i,j,rec.xMinimum(),rec.yMinimum(),rec.xMaximum(),rec.yMaximum())
        fileGrid.write(s)
        print "rec: "+rec.toString()
        canvas.setExtent(rec)
        canvas.refresh()
        filename = "test_%d_%d.txt" % (i,j)
        fileObj = open(filename,"w")
        labels = canvas.mapRenderer().labelingEngine().labelsWithinRect(fullext)
        for l in labels:
           # print l.labelText,l.cornerPoints[0].x(),l.cornerPoints[0].y(),l.rotation
            s = "%s,%f,%f,%f\n" % (l.labelText.encode("utf-8"),l.cornerPoints[0].x(),l.cornerPoints[0].y(),l.rotation)
            fileObj.write(s)
        fileObj.close()
        print "save: "+filename;


fileGrid.close()
print "END"
```

it writes labels to txt file with x and y coordinates and angle. I don't have any idea how to save labels for all maps in specific scale.

It should be noted that the angle in the txt file is in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) not degrees. If you load the file into QGIS you have to give the angle in degrees. This can be done by `*180/pi`. In QGIS you can type the expression `"column with the angle"*180/pi` under

*properties>labels>placement>"icon besides rotation">expression*